# Flutter define icon color by textstyle

Tags: flutter, text, icons

I think I've hared that there is a Widget the gets a Textstyle and a list of children. The children can be Text-Widgets or Icon-Widgets and get the defining styles (and with that the color of the Icon) from that parent.
But I can't find that anywhere.
Do I remember that correctly, and if, what Widget was that?
Or am I just wrong about that?

Edit:
I thought it was this, but it don't seam to work the way I thought:

```
return RichText(
  strutStyle: StrutStyle.fromTextStyle(TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: "Add Object"),
      WidgetSpan(child: Icon(Icons.add))
    ]
  ),
 );
```

Comment: Can you include a sample snippet that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `DefaultTextStyle` widget which receives a `TextStyle` entity and will apply it to descendant `Text` widgets (as long as the descendant `Text` widgets do not have explicit styles applied: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html

When talking about the icons as well, there is no dedicated widget for that since you would usually define that as part of your overall theme as `ThemeData` (usually provided in `MaterialApp`)